# Python defining function error

Tags: python, function

I need to make a function that will post an image in four segments on a canvas using turtle graphics, I have written the following functions

```
def locations(local):
# Move to location
    if local[1] =='Location 1':
        goto(-300,0)

    elif local[1] == "Location 2":
        goto(-150,0)

    elif local[1] == 'Location 3':
        goto(0,0)

    elif local[1] == "Location 4":
        goto(150,0)

# Get correct Orientation
    if local [2] == "Upright":
        setheading(0)
    elif local [2] == "Upside down":
        setheading(180)


def paste_up (arrangement):
    for sheets in arrangement:
        if (len(sheets)>1):
            print(sheets[1])
            for places in "Data_sets":
            if sheets [0] == 'Sheet A':
                locations(local)
                sheeta()
            elif sheets [0] == "Sheet B":
                sheetb()
            elif sheets [0] == 'Sheet C':
                sheetc()
            elif sheets [0] == 'Sheet D':
                sheetd()
```

I get this error:

> NameError: name 'local' is not defined

How can I make my paste_up function refer to my locations function?

Comment: where do you get the error?

Comment: You don't write where the error occurs, i. e. you fail to supply the full stack trace. Besides, check your indent: the way you posted it looks as if `paste_up()` is defined inside `locations()`. If it is defined on top level, then it is right: there is no `local` defined.

Comment: It looks like `paste_up` is actually a top-level function and @EdChum's edit messed up the indentation.

Comment: @interjay yup I messed up the edit, someone needs to approve the edits

Comment: You have indented the function paste_up wrongly. Moreover, you have not given the full code like where is the local variable defined. Just change it accordingly and then please state clearly what is the error and what's the trace for that error.

Comment: Your `paste_up` function refers to a `local` variable, but no such variable exists at that scope. It isn't clear what value you want to pass into `locations`.

Comment: You currently trying to call a function within `paste_up` with the incorrect input/non existing input argument.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming `paste_up` is defined OUTSIDE `locations`**, 
you call `locations(local)` here:

```
if sheets [0] == 'Sheet A':
    locations(local)
```

but of course that `local` name was never defined. You'll have to add a parameter or define it (but since you give no info of what that is or where it comes from, that's all I can say)

**Assuming `paste_up` is actually defined INSIDE `locations`**, your code looks fine and you'll have to give us a traceback that says *where* the error occurs.